# Odd network performance difference between two Windows machines affected by VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

Network includes a Win 10 machine ("Desktop"), a Win 11 machine ("Laptop"), and a router (Netgear R9000/DD-WRT) running a Wireguard VPN.

Desktop and Laptop connect through the same network switch.  I have tried using different ports on the switch to see if that made a difference.

If I turn off the VPN, Desktop and Laptop get the same network performance (according to Speedtest), both very close to the quoted network speed of my ISP (500Mbps). So network performance of Desktop seems good.

If I turn on the VPN, performance on Laptop is very slightly degraded (as expected with a VPN active).  However, performance on Desktop is approximately halved.

I have investigated lots of network tuning suggestions for Desktop with no luck.  My best guess was an MTU issue, but setting Desktop to the same MTU as the Wireguard interface didn't help.

I am at a loss to figure out why enabling a VPN on a router so dramatically impacts the network performance of Desktop but has nearly no impact on Laptop.  Would appreciate any pointers towards speeding Desktop up to the same speed as Laptop.

Comment: FWIW, such MTU changes would only have the opposite effect – the physical interface's MTU must stay larger (or rather, the tunnel MTU must be smaller) to account for the tunnel protocol overhead.

Comment: Simply put, a VPN will slow your connection down, because your traffic is going through the VPN server: it's an extra step in the process.

Comment: @Mastaxx: Yes, I'm aware a VPN slows down traffic.  As explained in my question, the issue is why does turning on a VPN in a router affect one machine much more than another?